# Track calls as conversions

Tags: seo, google-analytics, google-ads-api

I've got a responsive website that changes to match the screen resolution of the user. One of the changes is a "call us" button that shows up when the website is viewed on a smart phone. When a user clicks the button (it's a `<a href="tel:000-000-0000">` style link), I need to be able to track that as a conversion in both Adwords and Google Analytics.

Would it work to implement a redirect to another page that contains tracking code, before redirecting back to the `tel:` link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easier to use a virtual pageview with an javascript onclick event eventhandler:

```
<a onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/tel/0000-000-0000']);return false" href="tel:000-000-0000">
```

However I'm not sure that those links can be consideres pageviews (since they have not content), so maybe it's better to count them as events (works pretty much the same but with an _trackEvent-Call instead _trackPageview).

Virtual Pageview Documentation:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/asyncMigrationExamples#VirtualPageviews

Event Tracking Documentation
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/asyncMigrationExamples#EventTracking

Comment: Is there a way with pageview tracking or event tracking to count the click as a goal completion? For example, my goal page is /thank_you.php. If I use an onClick event to trigger a manual pageview of /thank_you.php, will the be counted as a goal completion?

Comment: Works with both. A virtual pageview is from the point of the Analytics interface no different than a real pageview, so you can use an url based goal. But there are also event based goals.  The difference is that you cannot have funnel visualization for event based goals (since by definition they have only one step).

Comment: Ok, so I have the following implemented: `<a href="tel:0000000000" onClick="javascript: _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/thank_you.php']);">000-000-0000</a>`. In my Google Analytics account I have /thank_you.php setup as a goal. Does that look correct?